# Fatal error trying to connect to Bitbucket

Tags: git, centos, repository, bitbucket, vps

I'm trying to git pull from Bitbucket via https on my CentOS VPS, while this worked just a few weeks ago it doesn't today.

**Giving me this error:**
Fatal: unable to access 'https://username@bitbucket.org/repositoryname/repositoryname.git/': Cannot communicate securely with peer no common encryption algorithm(s).

I might have changed my password which could have caused this problem maybe? But shouldn't it give me a prompt to re-enter it? Tried unsetting my username and password but that didn't work.

Pushing from my local device to Bitbucket works fine while using the same account, it's just the connection from my VPS to Bitbucket that's not working for some reason.

Comment: What version of CentOS are you using?  What version of Git are you using?  Is it the distro version, or did you get it from elsewhere?

Comment: Running CentOS 7.0 64-Bit and Git version 1.8.3.1. I'm not sure if it's distro version but I believe so, someone else installed it on the server and I'm not as knowledgeable on Git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're running an old and out-of-date version of CentOS 7.  The original CentOS 7.0 release didn't include important features in its TLS libraries, such as TLS 1.2 and elliptic curve support.

As a result, there are no cipher suites (sets of cryptographic algorithms) that are in common between the server (Bitbucket) and the client (Git).  There's therefore no way to negotiate a shared algorithm or an encrypted connection.  This probably has failed now since Bitbucket removed obsolete ciphers, knowing that all up-to-date systems will have a robust set of secure cipher suites that can be used.

The thing to do is to update your system to the latest CentOS 7 version (7.7) with `yum`.  7.0 is very old and has multiple known security problems, and your version of Git is probably not patched, either.  Right now, a CentOS 7.0 system is a hazard to the general Internet.

If you really can't update to the latest version, then you can try using an SSH remote with an SSH key.  Note that the version of OpenSSH in CentOS 7.0 is not great, either, so try to use a key type other than RSA or DSA if you have to do this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer, it helped me getting it fixed with an SSH key. I know  everything should be updated but was in a hurry to get something online.

I will soon update everything and do it the right way, thank you very much!